# Significance of Virtual Function's in C++

Tags: c++14

I am learning C++ and came around virtual functions. I got to know that virtual functions are the one declared in the base class and used in the derived class. On the basis of definition I tried to make two simple programs. Please see below :

This Program is using virtual keyword :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Name {

    public :
            Virtual void myName() {
                cout << "My First Name is Varun" << endl ;
            }

};

class LName: public Name{

    public :
           void myName() {

               cout << "My Last Name is Srivastava" << endl;

           }

};

int main() {

    Name *name = new Name();
    name -> myName();
    LName *lname = new LName();
    lname -> myName();

    Name *nm;
    LName ln;

    nm = &ln;
    nm -> myName();
    ln.myName();


}
```

Output :

```
My First Name is Varun
My Last Name is Srivastava
My Last Name is Srivastava
My Last Name is Srivastava
```

Below example is without virtual keyword :

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Name {

    public :
            void myName() {
                cout << "My First Name is Varun" << endl ;
            }

};

class LName: public Name{

    public :
           void myName() {

               cout << "My Last Name is Srivastava" << endl;

           }

};

int main() {

    Name *name = new Name();
    name -> myName();
    LName *lname = new LName();
    lname -> myName();

    Name *nm;
    LName ln;

    nm = &ln;
    nm -> myName();
    ln.myName();


}
```

Output :

```
My First Name is Varun
My Last Name is Srivastava
My First Name is Varun
My Last Name is Srivastava
```

Here I can see the difference, but I am not able to get the why there is difference in the output and what exactly is "virtual" keyword doing.

Comment: read up on virtual functions, eg :https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/virtual-function-cpp/

Comment: In the statement  `nm->myName()`, the result is a call to `Name::myName()` (the base class version) if the function is not a virtual member of `Name`, and to `LName::myName()`  (the version corresponding to the type of the ACTUAL object that `nm` points to) if it IS a virtual member of `Name`.   Also, this is true for ALL versions of C++, not just C++14.

Comment: @Thanks Peter, your explanation helped me.